# How to use Raspberry Pi 4 to add wireless capability to my vinyl turntable?

Tags: audio, pi-4, home-automation, hifiberry, speakers

Given an Apple HomePod and a non-wireless vinyl turntable, I’m looking for recommendations on how to wirelessly connect the two.

My idea is to use a Raspberry Pi 4 to connect the turntable to my iPhone via WiFi or Bluetooth and then stream to the HomePod using airplay from there? Perhaps something like this is useful:

https://thepihut.com/collections/raspberry-pi-hats/products/hifiberry-dac-adc

Does anyone have any other ideas or is able to point me towards some instructions to do this?

Comment: Greetings, and welcome to RPi SE. Without trying to be a total [wet blanket](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=wet%20blanket), this looks problematic to me. Cost and questionable support are my two biggest concerns. I've also had issues with that vendor. If you're not concerned about the money, have some experience dealing with custom kernels - or are looking for a learning project, this might be the ticket. Maybe you should keep looking?

Comment: Re Seamus's point, you could try with a cheap generic USB dongle first. That might be sufficient in the end anyway and requires no special drivers, kernels, configuration, etc.

Comment: What output options do you have from the turntable?  I know some modern ones have USB but I get the feeling your is analog only...  if so, is it designed for an amp or headphones?